# Python mutiply columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

my current sample dataframe is as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = '''\
X1,X2,Y
5,8,1
8,9,1
3,6,1
7,7,1
1,3,1
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Which looks as:

```
   X1  X2  Y
0   5   8  1
1   8   9  1
2   3   6  1
3   7   7  1
4   1   3  1
```

I want to multiply and add as follows :-

a= which is sum of (X1*y) -all X1 multiplied by respective Y in that row

```
a=(5*1)+(8*1)+(3*1)+(7*1)+(1*1) =24
```

b= which is sum of (X2*y) -all X2 multiplied by respective Y in that row

Comment: Could you please post the expected output for the given toy example? I am really confused by the usage of the word "all" in the definition of a. By "all", do you mean sum of the column? And pls add brackets for computations.

Comment: a=(5*1)+(8*1)+(3*1)+(7*1)+(1*1) =24 @kate-melnykova

Comment: can you add a dataframe to the end of your question which displays the expected output please

Comment: a is my expected output @baxx

Comment: This is not that hard for many python programmers, could you please let us know what you have tried and at which point you are stuck? That way, you will learn and progress further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to do it manually:

```
a = (df['X1'] * df['Y']).sum() # 24
b = (df['X2'] * df['Y']).sum() # 33
```

If you have a lot of columns to multiply by `Y`, you may want to take advantage of numpy's array broadcasting:

```
(df[['X1', 'X2']] * df['Y'].values[:, None]).sum()
```

Result:

```
X1    24
X2    33
dtype: int64
```